# Send message to all computers connected on my router

Tags: windows

Is there a way I can configure my router to be able to send message to all computers connected to it via WiFi.

For instance i tried using `msg * "Message"` however it seems no one is getting any. I would like to setup these as automated messages for instance before router is rebooted all PCs would see a Windows dialog box with the message the kind you get with `"Net send"` or `"MSG`" commands in windows.

I have a Linksys router.

Comment: What OS? w/o that info, it's hard to say.

Comment: Would be Windows 7/8. 3 PCs have Windows 8 2 have Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

The netsend command has been depreciated since windowsxp. It has as you suggest been replaces with the msg.exe command, however this is not available in all versions of 7 and 8.

Refer to:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/msgexe-netsend-anything-availible-on-windows-7/e9743edc-afa9-4942-b1c7-66baf443067b

Perhaps you may have luck with this third party app?

http://www.winsentmessenger.com/sent/

Comment: Is there a better tool maybe one where i could just enter the ip of a PC on router and it would send it the message.